# Error Handling in C

Tags: c, error-handling

Hello there and thank you for stopping by.

**The solution has been found by making use of proprietary code. See bottom for used code.
Thanks everybody for input and help!**

I'm fairly new to C programming (meaning I coded some very basic stuff). At the moment, I'm writing a script in C language. I've tried searching the site, but no examples seem applicable to my case, or simply do not work.
What it does is basically opening a file (or a batch of multiple files), telling the master program to plot a graph of selected string (the open_curve() is a program specific function).

Now my problem is that one of the strings (lets say string2 in the code below) is not always present. When it's missing, the script produces an error and quits. How to stop this happening? VBA has an option many people loathe, but I regard it to be quite useful in this situation: On Error resume next. I know it might be missing and it is not of importance in this case. When it's there I need it. When it's not, too bad... so if no errors pop up and the value is missing, that is perfectly fine.
Question is, how can I get a similar functionality in C?

```
#define NMAX 10 // max. Anzahl Dateien
string n[NMAX]; // Global wegen Stack!

void main(void)
{
string *q;
int i,nmax=NMAX;
nmax=GetOpenFileName(n, nmax, "Daten-Dateien (*.DAT)", "*.DAT");



    for (i=0, q=n; i<nmax; i++,q++)
    {


            ql.open_file(.file=*q);
            close_curve();
            open_curve(.name="\"String1\"");
            open_curve(.name="\"String2\"");
            open_curve(.name="\"String3\"");


            printf("File %2d: %s\n",i,*q);

    }   
getch();
}
```

The prototype:

```
int [ql.]open_curve(.name = string[, .no = int,

                     .color = int, .lthick = int,

                     .linetype = int,

                     .marker = int, .drawall = int,

                     .markersize = float,

                     .bars = int, .ynull = float,

                     .ymin = float, .ymax = float,

                     .xmin = float, .xmax = float,

                     .yaxis = int,  .xaxis = int,

                     .axis = int,  .colsrc = int,

                     .xsignal = string, .csignal = string,

                     .index = string, 

                     .xfrom = float, .xuntil = float,

                     .usemarker = int]);
```

The Code, with my problem solved:
Now returns empty when not found.

```
for (i=0, q=n; i<nmax; i++,q++)
        {


                ql.open_file(.file=*q);
                close_curve();
                open_curve(.name="\"String1\"");
Warninglevel = 2;
            Errorlevel3 = 3; // Fehler nicht melden, weitermachen
                err = open_curve(.name="\"String2\"");
            Errorlevel3 = 0;
            Warninglevel = 0;               
                open_curve(.name="\"String3\"");


                printf("File %2d: %s\n",i,*q);

        }   
    getch();
    }
```

with the warning and error levels explained as following:

```
extern int Warninglevel  - Warnings will...

                            0 - Produce an Error box
                            1 - be ignored
                            2 - be ignored

 extern int Errorlevel1   - Errors will...

                       0 - Produce an Error box (popup) and cancel script
                       1 - Produce an Error box and continue script                       2 - ignored and cancel script.
```

Comment: what do you mean with "produces an error", does the program crash? Normally the way in C to handle potential errors is to check return codes of functions.

Comment: The main program gives error box stating that an error has occurred on the line of the 'open_curve(.name="\"String2\"");', when clicked on OK it gives another error box informing me that the program has been terminated.

Comment: The open_curve function is some kind of library that you use? Maybe there is a function to check for existence first before trying to open it. What does the prototype of open_curve look like?

Comment: Check the documentation of `ql.open_file` -- it may return a value that indicates whether it successfully opened the file.

Comment: btw the return type for main is int not void

Comment: I checked the manual, but I can't seem to find an equivalent of the check for existence. I'll add the prototype to the question.
Documentation only gives the prototype and an explanation of the parameters.

Comment: Are you sure that's C? We do not have default values for arguments, nor named parameters.

Comment: Barmar, thanks! That pointed me in the right direction!
Turns out the master file is having some kind of 'On Error Resume Next' function.
(also see my comment on the first answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in C that corresponds to `On Error Resume Next`.

It is possible to catch errors using signal handling, but it is not the preferred way to do error checking in C.

Instead, best practice is to code defensively. Any variable that is allowed to be `NULL` should be checked before it is used.

In your case the code could look like this:

```
char *name;   // In reality

name = get_graph_name();  // Generate a name somehow, or null.

if (name != NULL) {    // Only open the curve if we have a name.
    open_curve(name);
}
```

Comment: You propaby meant `NULL` where you wrote `null` didn't you?

Comment: @alk Thanks. Fixed it. I've been coding way to much Java in recent years.